# How to compile nuke NDK plugins in C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, visual-c++

I am new to developing plugins for Nuke using its NDK . I followed some tutorials and guides and set up my VS Code as per the guides when I am compiling I am getting several errors thrown at some of which I dont understand

The following are the error codes I recieved
E0145 which say DD::Image::something something is not initalised
C4996
C2664
and the above two with varying error messages

I have set up VS Code as per the NDK and by following some tutorials whose code was executed without any errors

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to link the `./include` folder in your configuration. I'm learning myself too these days.. I got it working after following: [THIS](https://maxvanleeuwen.com/project/nuke-ndk/) , I hope this helps you!